# useHistory - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When the home button is pressed I want to redirect it to the home page '/ '. But I am getting this error. What can I do ? :

```
import { Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min';
const history = useHistory();

const homeButtonOnClickHandler = () =>{
    history.push("/");
}
  
<Router>
    <Header homeButtonOnClickHandler={homeButtonOnClickHandler}/>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/result'>
            <Result
                ingredients={ingredients}
                total={() => hesapla()} 
            />
        </Route>

        <Route path='/'>
            <Home
                ingredients={ingredients} 
                total={() => calculate()} 
                ingredientAdd={(i) => ingredientAdd(i)}
                ingredientRemove={(i) => ingredientRemove(i)}
                selectedIngredients={ingredients}
                isOrder={number}
            />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Did you mean to include an error readout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `history` hook outside of `Router`. Write your function inside `Header` component.

Try this inside `Header` component

```
const history = useHistory();

const homeButtonOnClickHandler = () =>{
            history.push('/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put hook and handler into component like here: [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-react-with-the-history-api)